# Why above view overlaps below view?

Tags: android, view

For some reason I m not able to cover my button.

Thats my XML. All wrapped inside `RelativeLayout` with no special attribute sets.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/report_issue"
    android:text="@string/report_issue"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_report_issue"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/service_dialog_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/red_orange"/>
```

And this is how it looks like.
[image]

`Button` is above `FrameLayout` and I cant find out why. What I want to achieve is cover button with `FrameLayout` - to have only red part visible.

I tried many combinations but nothing helped.

Comment: please post the entire xml. Is `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` correct for the button? Looks more like 200dp

Comment: @kristyna Please post complete XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API level 21, Buttons have high elevation so they appear on top irrespective of their order in View.

You can use `android:elevation"` in your views. Make sure `android:elevation` is higher in a view which you want to appear on top.

Why you are not using `FrameLayout` for drawing views on top of each other.

Note - `android:elevation"` is introduced after API level 21.

Comment: Omg... Thanks, I didn't notice.